# How would I set a thread priority in Rust in macOS?

Tags: macos, unix, rust, libc

The crate [thread-priority](https://docs.rs/thread-priority/0.2.4/thread_priority/) is only supported on Windows and Linux operating systems but unfortunately isn't supported for macOS. So the only crate I found that would support macOS was [libc](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.100/libc/) but it lacks documentation

The application I'm making needs global key press events which has to be reliable and time sensitive, so to test the application in development, I used `sudo nice -n -20 cargo run` and the difference was clear that the code I tried for libc crate wasn't working.

This is the code I tried for libc:

```rust
fn main() {
  unsafe {
     libc::setpriority(libc::PRIO_PROCESS, 0, -20);
  }
}
```

Someone suggested me this for macOS in a Rust Discord Server which unfortunately didn't make any difference as well:

```rust
fn main() {
  unsafe {
     libc::setpriority(libc::PRIO_DARWIN_THREAD, 0, -20);
  }
}
```

Edit: As I would be publishing this CLI in Homebrew, a command without sudo is required to make it not suspicious to people installing it.

Comment: The equivalent of your `nice -n 20` command would be `libc::nice(-20)` but, as you did with `sudo`, you need privileges to increase priority (decrease niceness, with a negative value). You should check the result of the system-call.